# How to split a string with repeated delimiters?

Tags: r, regex

I have a list of movie names in the following format:

**Movie Names**
Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls (1995)

Twelve Monkeys (a.k.a. 12 Monkeys) (1995)

Seven (a.k.a. Se7en) (1995)

French Twist (Gazon maudit) (1995)

Rumble in the Bronx (Hont faan kui) (1995)

I am trying to split the year and form a new column.

**DATA.**
Note: edited by user Rui Barradas

```
x <- scan(what = character(), text = '
"Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls (1995)"
"Twelve Monkeys (a.k.a. 12 Monkeys) (1995)"
"Seven (a.k.a. Se7en) (1995)"
"French Twist (Gazon maudit) (1995)"
"Rumble in the Bronx (Hont faan kui) (1995)"
')
```

Comment: Not my downvote, but it happened because you showed zero effort.  Surely you have tried something?

Comment: It is a simple regex problem. I am not a regex Super User, but here it goes: `sub(".*\\(([[:digit:]]+)\\)$", "\\1", x)`. I will edit to add the appropriate tag.

Comment: Yes, Tim, I did. I had calculated the length of the string and then tried separating the last 6 character, namely, (YYYY), from the total but could not do so. Thanks anyway for the guidance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added some lookaround regex to make sure you don't get a year that is part of the movie title.

```
library(stringr)

x <- scan(what = character(), text = '
"Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls (1995)"
"Twelve Monkeys (a.k.a. 12 Monkeys) (1995)"
"Seven (a.k.a. Se7en) (1995)"
"French Twist (Gazon maudit) (1995)"
"Rumble in the Bronx (Hont faan kui) (1995)"
')

movie_title<-str_extract(x,".*?(?=\\s\\(\\d{4})")
year<-str_extract(x,"\\d{4}(?=\\))")
```

Comment: Thanks, Jose, after addition of few more lines, I could achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

you can use the `separate()` function of the package `tidyr` to split columns in a data.frame by a desired delimiter.

As the others stated, you can use regular expressions to look for patterns in your data. Below I use `(?=\\(\\d{4}\\))` to look for a pattern of 4 digits within a parenthesis (and set it as separator). You can combine that with the [positive lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `?=` to look for the pattern, but keeping it for later use.

```
# load package tidyr
require(tidyr)

# your data
x <- scan(what = character(), text = '
"Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls (1995)"
"Twelve Monkeys (a.k.a. 12 Monkeys) (1995)"
"Seven (a.k.a. Se7en) (1995)"
"French Twist (Gazon maudit) (1995)"
"Rumble in the Bronx (Hont faan kui) (1995)"
')

# to data.frame
x <- as.data.frame(x)

# split by delimiter (4 digits within parenthesis)
# and create two columns - movie name and year
x <- separate(x, col = x, into = c('movie', 'year'), 
         sep = "(?=\\(\\d{4}\\))")
```

## Output

```
> x
                                 movie   year
1      Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls  (1995)
2  Twelve Monkeys (a.k.a. 12 Monkeys)  (1995)
3                Seven (a.k.a. Se7en)  (1995)
4         French Twist (Gazon maudit)  (1995)
5 Rumble in the Bronx (Hont faan kui)  (1995)
```

Yo can get rid of the parenthesis in the year column later if you like.

```
x$year <- gsub("[\\(|\\)]", "", x$year)

> x
                                 movie year
1      Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls  1995
2  Twelve Monkeys (a.k.a. 12 Monkeys)  1995
3                Seven (a.k.a. Se7en)  1995
4         French Twist (Gazon maudit)  1995
5 Rumble in the Bronx (Hont faan kui)  1995
```

Comment: Thank you Alanisson for explaining the usage of regular expression.

Answer (score 0):

One solution in javascript, I believe the regex should be same in which ever language you are implementing this.

```
 var pattern = /\((\d{4})\)$/;
 pattern.exec("Ace Ventura: When Nature Calls (1995)")[0];
```

This should strip off the year info from the string.